# Object disappears when applying curve modifier

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, curve-modifier

I am trying to have an object's position map to a curve. I have drawn a curve, extended it a few times using an array modifier, converted it to a mesh to apply the modifier and then back to a curve, and created a cylinder to travel along the curve.

[image]

When I apply the curve modifier, the object disappears in object mode and isn't visible in render, but is still visible, unmodified, in edit mode. Changing the deform axis makes no difference.
[image: Cylinder disappears after applying modifier]

[image: Cylinder visible in edit mode.]

If I remove the modifier, the cylinder reappears. Strangely, if I open a new blank project and use the same technique, it works fine. So it seems to be an issue just in this project. Is there anyone with any idea of what is going on or why my object might be disappearing/not mapping?

Here is the file: https://pasteall.org/blend/5223d9832d2e43d1ac1ab31717a69796

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Just did! The link is in the question. Here it is again https://pasteall.org/blend/5223d9832d2e43d1ac1ab31717a69796 @moonboots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the *N* panel: Your curve has a X scale of 0, bring it back to 1 and rather go in *Edit* mode and scale 0 on X (or apply the scale of the object and bring its vertices radius back to 1). Then you just need to correctly orientate your cylinder, for example <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>90</kbd> in *Edit* mode then in the modifier choose *Deform Axis > Z* then move it on Y so that it follows the curve.